# Finding extrema of a complicated potential of 4 variables takes too long

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have this particular potential $V(\phi_1, \phi_2, \psi, \rho)$ of 4 variables and I'd like to find the extrema of this $V$ but both Solve and NDSolve seem to take hours without yielding any results - I eventually had to abort the evaluation every single time.

Here is my code and the definition of the potential

```
 V[ϕ1_, ϕ2_, ψ_, ρ_] := ρ^{-4} (1 - 
 Cos[2 ψ]^2 (Sinh[ϕ1]^2 - 
     Sinh[ϕ2]^2)^2) + ρ^2 (Cosh[2 ϕ1] + 
 Cosh[2 ϕ2]) + (1/16) ρ^8 (2 + 2 Sin[2 ψ]^2 - 
 2 Sin[2 ψ]^2 Cosh[2 (ϕ1 - ϕ2)] - Cosh[4 ϕ1] -
  Cosh[4 ϕ2])

 Solve[D[V[ϕ1, ϕ2, ψ, ρ], ϕ1] == 0 && 
D[V[ϕ1, ϕ2, ψ, ρ], ϕ2] == 0 && 
 D[V[ϕ1, ϕ2, ψ, ρ], ψ] == 0 && 
  D[V[ϕ1, ϕ2, ψ, ρ], ρ] == 
   0, {ϕ1, ϕ2, ψ, ρ}]
```

So I'd like to know if there is a way to ameliorate this problem? NDSolve does no better than Solve for my case. Could it be that the potential is too complicated for Mathematica to handle?

Comment: `FindArgMax[
  V[\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi], \[Rho]], {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi], \
\[Rho]}] // Chop` gives `{1.02826, 1.02826, 1., 0}` - reasonable?

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks !!! Will FindArgMax return multiple extrema if there are more than one?

Comment: Unfortunately, FindArgMax didn't return the value reported in the article that I am studying.

Comment: `NMaximize[
 V[\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi], \[Rho]], {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi],  \
\[Rho]}] ` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that, it failed to converge. The results don't make any sense. NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>

Comment: Is your potential V correct? If you change the term  `r^(-4) `  to `r^4 `,  and limit the angles, `NMaximize[{V2[\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi], \[Rho]], \[Rho] > 0, 
  0 <= \[Phi]1 <= 2 Pi, 0 <= \[Phi]2 <= 2 Pi, 
  0 <= \[Psi] <= 2 Pi}, {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Psi], \[Rho]}] `  you get a result `{5177.08, {Phi1 -> 6.28319, Phi2 -> 6.28319, Psi -> 
   4.58896, Rho -> 0.155153}} `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I double-checked, and the potential is correct as it is.